# SVG rect height setting not working on Firefox and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am working on [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v25ro7g5/). Why is the `height` animation not working on Firefox and MS Edge?

It is working fine on Chrome.

```js
$("#app").hover(function(){
    $('#fillup').animate({height: "320"},3000);
    console.log("In");
    }, function(){
    $('#fillup').animate({height: "0"},3000);
     console.log("Out");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 320 320" id="app">
  <rect  x="0" y="0" width="320" height="0" fill="#47f" id="fillup" />
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Edge and Firefox you must treat height as an attribute, as SVG 1.1 does rather than a style as SVG 2 proposes.

```js
$("#app").hover(function(){
    $('#fillup').animate(
        { height: 320 },
        {
            duration: 3000,
            step: function(now) { $(this).attr("height", now); }
        });
    console.log("In");
    }, function(){
    $('#fillup').animate(
        { height: 0 },
        {
            duration: 3000,
            step: function(now) { $(this).attr("height", now); }
        });
     console.log("Out");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 320 320" id="app">
  <rect  x="0" y="0" width="320" height="0" fill="#47f" id="fillup" />
 </svg>
```